# firefox font size varies with server

Tags: firefox

Simple html file...

```
<html>
<h1>TEXT</h1>
</html>
```

When I host the above locally on my mac (apache2) and access it with firefox (http ://localhost/text.html) it looks different than when I host this on an external server (also apache2, http ://myhost.org/test.html). No style sheet it loaded, why the difference in font size?

[Image Link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFDDA.jpg)

[Image Link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS7sl.jpg)

Many Thanks, -Duncan.

Comment: Have you tried to reset zoom for both domains? Press Ctrl+0 (zero).

Comment: Did you debug using Firebug or the developer tools how the values are calculated? Is the output encoding of both servers the same?

Comment: @myf - good call on the reset zoom! - Many thanks -D.

Answer (score 0):

Was a zoom issue. Thanks @myf View->Zoom->Reset fixes as suggested.
-D